# Custom trash icons does not refresh (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, trash

I changed Desktop Recycle Bin default icons to custom ones. One for empty and one for full. But the problem is that the icons dont switch by themselves. I have to manually refresh desktop for icons to change (full/empty).

Comment: Same thing happens here, and also happened in XP the same way. It refreshes on a reboot, or after the shell is restarted.    One possible way would be to hack the icon into the DLL itself where the system gets the original Icon, and dont try to change it in the system, which is not very practical.  Mabey if it was part of a theme itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I will post it here for others with same problem to see it. :)
You can do this by changing some values in registry. (Adding ,0 to the end of the .ico link)

You can read everything here:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/24761-recycle-bin-fix-custom-icons-not-refreshing.html